# How to specify a style for a QLabel which is a (non-direct) child of a QWidget with a specific name (name of the QWidget)?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to customize a style of a QLabel. This QLabel is a non-direct child of QWidget. And the only thing I have is an object name of the parent QWidget (not QLabel). Is it possible to do that?

I've tried something like this but no luck:

```css
QWidget#myObjectName QLabel 
{
    font-weight: normal;  
}
```

Reproduction example (C++):

```
auto parentWidget = new QWidget();
parentWidget->setObjectName("myObjectName")
auto labelToStylize = new QLabel();
labelToStylize.setParent(parentWidget);
```

Comment: Is "myObjectName" the object name of the QLabel?

Comment: hi there! No, it's an object name of the QWidget (non direct parent of QLabel)

Comment: You must provide a [MRE] to understand you better

Comment: Not sure if this is possible.
What are you doing with 'labelToStylize' after this code, adding it to some kind of QLayout I suppose? I think this will change it's parent in the first place..